# If statement does not work?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

it always go with else, even if txtUserName.Text = "Adm_A"
Why is that ?

```
If txtUserName.Text Like "Adm_?" Then
            Response.Redirect("AdminLoggedIn.aspx")
        Else
            Response.Redirect("LoggedIn.aspx")
        End If
```

Comment: This should work. Are you sure that the string it "Adm_A" ? Does it contain 5 characters?

Answer (score 1):

A simple console application to test your problem

```
Sub Main
    Dim test = "Adm_AA"
    CheckLike(test)
    test = "Adm_A"
    CheckLike(test)
    test = "Adm_A "   ' a space after the A'
    CheckLike(test)
End Sub

Sub CheckLike(ByVal toCheck as string)

    If toCheck Like "Adm_?" Then
        Console.WriteLine("Matched")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Not Matched")
    End If
End Sub
```

Results:

```
Not Matched
Matched
Not Matched
```

So there is something in your strings that it's not like you think it is.
Use the debugger and verify the if statement and its argument.
Also pay attention to the locale of the server where you run the webapp and the Option Compare used

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
If txtUserName.Text.Trim() Like "Adm_?" Then
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is because the question mark is a pattern operator. Please check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw(v=vs.71).aspx

Have you tried using contains instead of like?

Answer (score 0):

can you try this

If txtUserName.Text.Trim() Like "Adm?" Then

Answer (score 0):

How about checking if it starts with the "Adm_" string:

```
If txtUserName.Text.StartsWith("Adm_") Then
        Response.Redirect("AdminLoggedIn.aspx")
    Else
        Response.Redirect("LoggedIn.aspx")
    End If
```